# Searching for internal bus connections in Germany

Tags: germany, buses

How to search for internal bus connections in Germany, for example between Munich and Berlin?

[The question on Travel.SE about cheap bus lines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8458/cheap-bus-lines-in-germany-something-like-orangeways) gives many bus companies that offer inter-Germany bus connections. So if I'd like to find best connection for me (which could be by price, but as well by the departure/arrival hour) I'd have to go to all of the sites and check.

Are there some aggregating sites for Germany, where I can find all connections from all companies for given route? For Poland for example, there are sites like e-Podroznik

Comment: http://www.busliniensuche.de/ -> it's a part of the greg's answer

Comment: and also http://www.busticket.de/ , so the other question answer everything you want

Comment: Maybe both should be added to http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11648/is-there-a-list-of-online-public-transportation-planners/. I haven't found it because it's not tagged [buses] and initially targeted for inter-city transport, maybe it should be splitted to 2 canonical answers. I've enriched it for Polish bus planner, by occasion.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention an alternative: Deutsche Bahn (the German train network). Fast, reliable, comfortable, and accessible for non-German speaking people. OK, journeys are probably more money, but I'd say worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the two websites already mentioned in the comments, I can also recommend "Fahrtenfuchs" (https://www.fahrtenfuchs.de/). Moreover, there is another website that compares different ways of travel: "Verkehrsmittelvergleich" (http://www.verkehrsmittelvergleich.de/).

However, there is one major issue: Most of the websites that aggregate bus connections do not include all major bus companies. It might be worthwhile to use different aggregation websites.