# Bus search engines for Germany without place of arrival?

Tags: online-resources, germany, buses

So, I want to see if I can make a nice daytrip from **Germany** (to Germany or Netherlands, France... I live near the border so it would be nice if it included also the neighbouring countries) travelling by bus. I just have my departure and a day I want to travel. Now I want to see which destinations can be reached by bus. Is there a website which can offer me something like that?
[I already found an answer for my question related to flights](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27100/cheapest-flight-to-anywhere-at-any-given-time), but I am still looking for bus routes. I tried the search engines I found in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34046/searching-for-internal-bus-connections-in-germany/34473#34473) but they all need a place of arrival.

Comment: I live in North-Rhine-Westfalia. Since there are many bigger cities around me which offer nowadays those free bus services (like flixbus etc), it should not matter in which city I start.

Comment: Unforunately, bus services such as flixbus are neither free as in "free beer", nor free as in "free speech". Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I mean.. they're independent? Don't know the right term for that... I mean companies that were founded after the market was liberalized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a map which shows all destinations which can be reached from a city at [busliniensuche.de](http://www.busliniensuche.de/karte/).

[image: Screenshot of German map with bus destinations]

Answer (score 2):

The site for Eurolines lets you select the city in which you start your trip from a dropdown list, then it shows the favorite destinations by bus. You can try that but I am not sure you will find your city in the quick list.

https://www.eurolines.de/en

The list is in the inferior left corner of the site. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Since there are only a few bus lines with a large network, it makes sense to just look at their route maps and pick some destination that does not require a transfer:

Here are some links:

- https://www.flixbus.de/sites/default/files/flixbus-fernbusverbindungen.pdf
- https://www.adac-postbus.de/Haltestellen/

Answer (score 1):

At [Busbud](https://www.busbud.com/en/buses-to/Dusseldorf,NorthRhineWestphalia,Germany?currency=EUR) we're also working on this functionality, we have different international coverage than the link previously mentioned. You can access this by leaving the destination "going to" field empty while searching.
[image]